# Laravel Eloquent orWhere on relationships

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, where-clause

I've a Course model which has many Help model.

```php
public function helps() {
    return $this->hasMany(Help::class);
}
```

Now the problem is when i try to get helps of a specific course with where and orwhere I have a little problem.

```php
$helps = $course->helps()
    ->where(['from_id' => 497])->orWhere(['to_id' => 497])->get();
```

The result is correct when I try to get helps of course 1:

```php
"data": [
        {
            "id": 12,
            "message": "hi there",
            "from_id": 497,
            "to_id": 1,
            "course_id": 1,
        },
        {
            "id": 108,
            "message": "hi ...",
            "from_id": 1,
            "to_id": 497,
            "course_id": 1,
        },
        {
            "id": 197,
            "message": "ok body",
            "from_id": 1,
            "to_id": 497,
            "course_id": 1,
        }
    ]
```

But when I try to get helps of any course that has not helps, instead of empty array it returns the `orWhere` fields with neglecting the `$course->helps()`

This is the results for course 2 which has not any Helps:

```php
"data": [
        {
            "id": 108,
            "message": "hi ...",
            "from_id": 1,
            "to_id": 497,
            "course_id": 1,
        },
        {
            "id": 197,
            "message": "ok body",
            "from_id": 1,
            "to_id": 497,
            "course_id": 1,
        }
    ]
```

Comment: Have you tried to add `course_id` in where clause

Comment: @DeepakPatel In this way it works:     `$helps = Help::where('course_id', '=', $course->id)->where('from_id', '=', $user->id)
            ->orWhere('course_id', '=', $course->id)->where('to_id', '=', $user->id)->get();`    but why my way is wrong?

Comment: '$helps = $course->helps() ->where(['from_id' => 497])->orWhere(['to_id' => 497])->get();' gets only data with `form_id` or `to_id` specified by you not by the `course_id`

Comment: You can use this $course->with(['helps' =>function($q){
$q ->where(...);
}])->where(function($q){
$q->where(['from_id' => 497])->orWhere(['to_id' => 497]);
})

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is `orWhere`. To generate correct query you should wrap condition into additional closure.

```
$helps = $course->helps()->where(function($q) {
    $q->where('from_id', 497)->orWhere('to_id', 497)
})->get();
```

Wrapping with closure adds ( ) in desired place.

Now you will have condition where `A AND (B OR C)` and before you had `A AND B OR C` what really means `(A AND B) OR C`.

I also removed array syntax from `where` to keep it cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$helps = $course->helps->where('from_id', 497)->orWhere('to_id', 497);
```